# why is the display not updating

Tags: python, tkinter, countdown

i want to do a countdown but the changes are not showing until the final one. Example:

```
def countdown():
    # setup of window and other labels etc
    timer = calculated time # just placeholder
    countdown_time = Message(countdownWindow, text=timer, font=("Courier",16,"bold"), width=100)
    time.sleep(1)
    while timer != "00:00:00":
        timer = calculate time # this time will be a updated current time
        root.after(1000, countdown_time.configure(text=timer)
    root.after(1000, countdown)
```

the problem here is that it only opens the window once the final change has been complete, but I want it to update the label every time it is changed

Comment: try `root.update()`

Comment: You should not use `while` loop if `.after()` is used.

Answer (score 0):

according to your example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label
import time

def countdown():
    time_count = 0
    time.sleep(1)
    while time_count != 10:
        time_count += 1
        root.after(1000, lbl.configure(text=str(time_count)))
        root.update()
    root.after(1000, countdown)  # invokes an endless loop

root = Tk()
btn = Button(root, text="countdown", command=countdown)
btn.pack()
lbl = Label(root, text="")
lbl.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You dont need multiple `after` and you are breaking the use of `after` with `root.update()` and `time.sleep`

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria i did not question the logic behind his code, he wanted to know how to update the label

Comment: You should've. Because it is not encouraged to use `root.update` without understanding it properly.